# Making Highcharts scatter circle shadow

Tags: javascript, highcharts, shadow

I am using highcharts ([link](http://www.highcharts.com/)) to display some data. Everything looks fine except I could not figure it out how to make a drop-shadow on each scatter circle data. I have fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vgaJd/) for this.

And I tried this one too:

```
series: (function() {
    var seriesArray = new Array();
var bubbleColor = ['#5f97ba', '#c7edc0', '#fc9026'];
for(var n=0; n<inputData.length; n++) {
    seriesArray.push({
         shadow: true, // This is not working
     marker: {
         symbol: 'circle',
         radius: 8
    },
    name: '',
    color: bubbleColor[n],
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    data: [] // I have some data here
    return a;
        })()
```

I checked in their api documents but no success. How can I make a drop shadow on each scatter circle as shown in this mock-up![image: this mockup]

Answer (score 0):

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bubble.shadow has the information you're looking for:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
         shadow: true
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, it did not work. Can you please take a look at my fiddle?